# Can't install coffeescript on ubuntu LTS

Tags: coffeescript, npm

I'm trying to install coffee script on ubuntu 10.04. It hangs forever.  This is the output of 
npm install coffee-script --verbose:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'node',
npm verb cli   '/home/deployment/local/node/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   'coffee-script',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@1.0.23
npm info using node@v0.5.4-pre
npm verb config file /home/deployment/.npmrc
npm verb config file /home/deployment/local/node/etc/npmrc
npm verb into /home/deployment [ 'coffee-script' ]
npm verb cache add coffee-script
npm verb cache add [ 'coffee-script', null ]
npm verb parsed url { pathname: 'coffee-script',
npm verb parsed url   href: 'coffee-script' }
npm info addNamed [ 'coffee-script', '' ]
npm verb addNamed [ null, '' ]
npm verb GET coffee-script
npm verb raw, before any munging coffee-script
npm verb url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/',
npm verb url resolving   './coffee-script' ]
npm verb url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm verb url parsed { protocol: 'https:',
npm verb url parsed   slashes: true,
npm verb url parsed   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
npm verb url parsed   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
npm verb url parsed   href: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script',
npm verb url parsed   pathname: '/coffee-script' }
npm verb etag "51J8TC2ZNUASOLES8S4M8TNK3"
npm verb response https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm verb etag coffee-script from cache
npm verb GET coffee-script/1.1.2
npm verb raw, before any munging coffee-script/1.1.2
npm verb url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/',
npm verb url resolving   './coffee-script/1.1.2' ]
npm verb url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/1.1.2
npm verb url parsed { protocol: 'https:',
npm verb url parsed   slashes: true,
npm verb url parsed   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
npm verb url parsed   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
npm verb url parsed   href: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/1.1.2',
npm verb url parsed   pathname: '/coffee-script/1.1.2' }
npm verb etag "51J8TC2ZNUASOLES8S4M8TNK3"
npm verb response https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/1.1.2
npm verb etag coffee-script/1.1.2 from cache
npm verb bin dist [ null,
npm verb bin dist   { shasum: 'a530a19d050c37054d83ae6c8041fba0fcd61ed3',
npm verb bin dist     tarball: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script- 1.1.2.tgz' } ]
npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.1.2.tgz',
npm verb addRemoteTarball   'a530a19d050c37054d83ae6c8041fba0fcd61ed3' ]
npm verb mkdir (expected) error ENOENT, No such file or directory '/tmp/npm-1312820932485'
npm verb mkdir (expected) error ENOENT, No such file or directory '/tmp/npm-1312820932485/1312820932485-0.11148986197076738'
npm verb mkdir done: /tmp/npm-1312820932485/1312820932485-0.11148986197076738 755
npm info fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.1.2.tgz
npm verb fetch to /tmp/npm-1312820932485/1312820932485-0.11148986197076738/tmp.tgz
```

It seems to hang forever on the fetch.  When I wget that URL I get a message that the http certificate has expired.

Any suggestions??

Comment: I experienced a similar problem and was able to get it to install using `sudo`. Have you tried that?

Comment: All of the node stuff is installed locally to the user. When I installed node I ran configure with "./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node". I've done this successfully in the past when the user doesn't have sudo access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue. As you noted it's a problem with the ssl cert. I used

`wget --no-check-certificate https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.1.2.tgz`

then

`npm install -g coffee-script-1.1.2.tgz`

Answer (score 6):

Now you can just do

```
sudo apt-get install coffeescript
```

Answer (score 1):

Node in odd versions is considered to be unstable. Use the last release of the 0.4 branch instead and it should work (it did for me yesterday).

Comment: @TiansHUo Thanks, I'll try as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having trouble too in the last few days. I think there might be a problem with the package registry.

UPDATE: This definitely seems to be a [npm problem](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1234)

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Ubuntu have a fairly outdated node.js. These are the instructions from node.js's wiki (https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os):

> Obtaining a recent version of Node or installing on older Ubuntu and
>   other apt-based distributions may require a few extra steps. Example
>   install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo npm install coffee-script@1.1.2
```